# How to install mongodb 2.6.11 on ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: 18.04, mongodb

I Have tried to install MongoDB 2.6.11 on Ubuntu 18 LTS but unable to install it.
always it installs MongoDB 3.6 version.
cloud you please help.

Answer (score 7):

There are no Ubuntu packages with that old version of MongoDB for Bionic (18.04). So if you need exactly that version, you need to compile it yourself:

#### Step 1

Install required packages for the MongoDB build

```
$ sudo apt-get install git build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev python scons
```

#### Step 2

Clone the MongoDB repository from [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git) and checkout the release

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git
$ cd mongo/
$ git checkout r2.6.11
```

#### Step 3

Build and install MongoDB. Disabling the warnings as errors option is required, because the new gcc compiler will find more warnings in the old code. Optionally use `/opt/mongo` as installation location to avoid collisions with other MongoDB packages:

```
$ scons -j$(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo) \
      --disable-warnings-as-errors=DISABLE-WARNINGS-AS-ERRORS \
      --prefix=/opt/mongo \
      -Q install
```

#### Step 4

Start MongoDB

```
$ /opt/mongo/bin/mongod
```

Comment: I followed these steps. Compilation goes fine but the mongod command not exiting, client is failing with `mongo got signal 11 (Segmentation fault)`, do you know any solution for this?

Comment: If the `mongod` is missing, something went wrong with the compilation/installation. Check for error messages in the `scons` output

Comment: It's not that `mongod` is missing. It's when I run it like `/path/mongod --config /configpath`, the command is not exiting and gets stuck. If i do `ps` from another ssh session i see the mongod process is running. When I tried connecting using `mongo` client. I am getting the above error.

Comment: Yes I am also seeing this segmentation fault on the `mongo` client... This is a typical problem with self complied, very old software... you can try to fix it or update to a newer version

Comment: Yes, I have also given up. Installed the latest stable and testing my application on that.